# Mediaplayer stop working when internet gets off or using vpn

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I have a recyclerview with different buttons that plays different sounds that it takes from url and it works fine but when you turn the Internet off or using vpn and turning back to the app it is not playing the sound
What can I do to stop this problem ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I asked this question  and no one answered  but then I found that the problem was because of the link I was using and I tried another link and it worked by the way I didn't delet my post maby someone had the same problem